# How can I use a token to display the node body summary?

Tags: tokens

I'm trying to use a token to show the body summary of a node on Drupal 7.

The **Replacement Patterns** area gives the following information:

- Body
- [node:body:?]
- The main body text of the node. The following properties may be appended to the token: value (Text), summary (Summary), format (Text format)

However, I don't understand what "append" means in this context.  I tried [node:body:summary] and [node:body:?summary], but neither works.  What am I supposed to do to get the summary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct tokens are [node:body] and [node:summary].
Yoy should probably check http://drupal.org/node/1295524 if you experience problems with summary tag

Answer (score 4):

Replace *?* with any of the following:

- value
- summary
- format

The token you use will look like one of the following:

- [node:body:value]
- [node:body:summary]
- [node:body:format]

Answer (score -2):

If using a view you can format the body field using the formatter.

[image: Formatter]

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I'm not using a View.  I'd like to know how to do it with tokens.